# Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone and SIGBRT

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, sigabrt

Hello i'm trying to built an application using ThoMoNetworking.framework. App works fine on device but on simulator i get that in console with zombies enabled

```
2012-07-18 23:54:11.043 testApp[4048:11303] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2012-07-18 23:54:11.042 testApp[4048:14807] Netservice is about to be published.
2012-07-18 23:54:11.795 testApp[4048:14807] Netservice has been published.
2012-07-18 23:54:12.045 testApp[4048:14f03] NetService _testApp._tcp. offered by mpla (2)
2012-07-18 23:54:12.073 testApp[4048:14f03] Resolved Server Address mpla.local.
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
(null) called from function ServerStubAcceptCallback in image testApp.
(lldb)
```

App used to be ok on older versions of Xcode and simulators.

build logs

```
Build target Remi's Chat App

ProcessInfoPlistFile "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Info.plist" Remi_s_Chat_App-Info.plist
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility Remi_s_Chat_App-Info.plist -genpkginfo "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/PkgInfo" -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Info.plist"

CompileXIB MainWindow.xib
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/MainWindow.nib" "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/MainWindow.xib" --sdk /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk

CompileXIB Remi_s_Chat_AppViewController.xib
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Remi_s_Chat_AppViewController.nib" "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/Remi_s_Chat_AppViewController.xib" --sdk /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk

2012-07-18 23:13:30.196 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[3098:14603] CFPreferences: user home directory at file://localhost/Users/zaab/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/User/ is unavailable. User domains will be volatile.scheduled GC timer for 0.000000 second
CpResource icon.png "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/icon.png"
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/icon.png" "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app"

CpResource Default.png "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Default.png"
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/Default.png" "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app"

CompileC "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/Remi_s_Chat_AppViewController.o" Classes/Remi_s_Chat_AppViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-project-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include" -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources" "-F/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/.." "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app" -include "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix-boaopykcsgtofmcpwdnuwuwmwnmg/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix.pch" -c "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/Classes/Remi_s_Chat_AppViewController.m" -o "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/Remi_s_Chat_AppViewController.o"

CompileC "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o" main.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-project-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include" -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources" "-F/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/.." "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app" -include "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix-boaopykcsgtofmcpwdnuwuwmwnmg/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix.pch" -c "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/main.m" -o "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o"

CompileC "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/Remi_s_Chat_AppAppDelegate.o" Classes/Remi_s_Chat_AppAppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-project-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include" -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources" "-F/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/.." "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app" -include "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix-boaopykcsgtofmcpwdnuwuwmwnmg/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix.pch" -c "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/Classes/Remi_s_Chat_AppAppDelegate.m" -o "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/Remi_s_Chat_AppAppDelegate.o"

CompileC "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSPatches.o" Classes/NSPatches.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Remi's Chat App-project-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include" -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/DerivedSources" "-F/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/.." "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app" -include "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix-boaopykcsgtofmcpwdnuwuwmwnmg/Remi_s_Chat_App_Prefix.pch" -c "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/Classes/NSPatches.m" -o "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSPatches.o"

Ld "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Remi's Chat App" normal i386
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk "-L/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app/.." "-F/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app" -filelist "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Intermediates/Remi's Chat App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.build/Objects-normal/i386/Remi's Chat App.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -fobjc-link-runtime -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework ThoMoNetworking -o "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Remi's Chat App"

GenerateDSYMFile "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app.dSYM" "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Remi's Chat App"
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app/Remi's Chat App" -o "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app.dSYM"

Touch "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app"
    cd "/Users/zaab/Desktop/zaabs chat app"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c "/Users/zaab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Remi's_Chat_App-ekylhajxuveoreakgvsugdpiadtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Remi's Chat App.app"
```

Comment: Well, this is somewhat of a misnomer since you cannot use a Framework directly with iOS, no? I don't know the particulars of this, but I assume there is a ".a" in that file. In terminal try this "file <name>.a" and make sure you see a i386 library inside.

Comment: no i don't see any a libraries do you mean static? Can i make them my self? and how? Why then on device everything works perfect

Comment: If you want to solve this you are going to have to dig deeper. There is no such thing as a Framework linking in iOS - it can in OSX but not on the Mac. So somewhere there is a static library. Maybe try google to find out more on this external library/framework.

Comment: OK but there in no .a library only some .h files and on device app is working like charm!

Comment: So you never mentioned you were using a beta version of Xcode, and building for iOS 6. That would have been a big help to know up front. That is really critical information to know.

Comment: i also tried it on 4.3 for ios 5.1 with no luck so i don't think that is the problem! Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but its more text than I can enter in a comment. So I downloaded this framework to take a peek at it. The library itself has two "frameworks" - one for OSX use and the other for iOS use. The iOS library (minus the .a) is there, and it contains all the requisite architectures:

$ file ./ThoMoNetworking.framework/ThoMoNetworking
./ThoMoNetworking.framework/ThoMoNetworking: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
./ThoMoNetworking.framework/ThoMoNetworking (for architecture armv6):   current ar archive random library
./ThoMoNetworking.framework/ThoMoNetworking (for architecture armv7):   current ar archive random library
./ThoMoNetworking.framework/ThoMoNetworking (for architecture i386):    current ar archive random library

Now, the OSX framework has a binary called ThoMoNetworking with these architectures:

$ file ThoMoNetworking
ThoMoNetworking: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
ThoMoNetworking (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
ThoMoNetworking (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
ThoMoNetworking (for architecture ppc7400): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc

So, lets suppose you installed BOTH of these frameworks on your computer. If somehow the OSX framework is looked at by the linker when you build for the Simulator, it thinks it can dynamically load this at run time, which of course it cannot.

So, if you have that framework installed in your Frameworks folder, I'd get rid of it. Then, just double check that you get the same result as I did running "file".

In any case, you can remove every version of ThoMoNetworking on your computer (use SpotLight to be sure), then re-download ThoMoNetworking, and ONLY install the iPhone framework.

Add a comment below when you do that, with the results, and if its still broken we can continue probing.

EDIT:
I just created a project in Xcode and downloaded the framework, added it, then started up a server with these lines in viewDidLoad:

// Assume myServer exists
   ThoMoServerStub *myServer = [[ThoMoServerStub alloc] initWithProtocolIdentifier:@"helloThoMo"];
   [myServer start];
   [myServer sendToAllClients:@"Howdie"];

It worked perfectly. Now, I'm using Xcode 4.4. The compiler is set to "Apple LLVM 4.0". I addd the framework, then made sure it was included in the library section (which it was). I ran in simulator just fine. The Architectures setting had the "ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT" shown in gray.

You said you get an error with Zombies on - why are they on? Turn them off and see what happens. Then, maybe some issue with ServerStubAcceptCallback? Do you register a callback that is sent? Put some logs there.

Comment: yeah i don't have for osx installed and the ios framework is located in my app folder! I also tried setting framework in Xcode frameworks but still no luck!

Comment: Try to delete it, then add it back. There of course is the possibility that for some reason it won't link with 5.1. I did notice on the ThoMoNetworking site that they offer to help with people having trouble - you should post a question to them directly. One other idea - when you build for the simulator, look in the build log, and expand the actual load line, and see what it shows. You should in any case edit your question to show that information - it might help. For sure you should see ThoMoNetworking in the load command line, along with any complaints or errors. Compare with iOS build.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info i'll post them here as soon as possible!

Comment: no luck tried everything so far! any help or thoughts about that would be great help!

Comment: i also sent them an e-mail but no answer yet! So still waiting! Debugging on real device for every test could seriously damage your brain...

Comment: Please grab the link line from a simulator build so we can see what its doing, and the result and any error messages. You have to click on the right side - a little widget pops up and lets you see the actual text. Edit your question and add that info please.